# Get duplicates in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an NSArray which contains a few duplicate objects. I want to print which objects are getting duplicated, for example:

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: A, B, C, A, B];
```

Now I want to print in my console `A` & `B` as these are duplicated.

How do I do this?

Comment: Define duplicate. How are the equal ? Same object or same content

Comment: You mean as in "duplicate question"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an NSCountedSet and only print the elements that returns a number>1 for `countForObject:` method

Answer (score 11):

You can use `NSCountedSet` for this. you can add all the objects in a counted set, then use the `countForObject`: method to find out how often each object appears. read about [NSCountedSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for further reference

Comment: 30 seconds faster than me :)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably far from perfect, but it works

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"b", @"v", @"f", @"f", nil];

NSMutableArray *un_array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *dupArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (id obj in array)
{
    if (![un_array containsObject:obj])
        [un_array addObject:obj];
    else
        [dupArray addObject:obj];
}

NSLog(@"DUPLICATES:");
for (id obj in dupArray)
    NSLog(@"%@", [obj description]);
```

Comment: It's important for a developer to pick their battles. Yes, it's the not the best way to do this, especially once the array gets even a little large. But for tiny arrays it might be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to sort the array and look for adjacent duplicates.  Probably a little slower than using a hashed set approach, but the same basic "big O".